# Grouplike and idempotent monoids

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Call a monoid group-like if it embeds into its group completion. There exists an obvious tension between group-like and idempotent monoids in that a group cannot contain non-trivial idempotent elements, so any idempotent elements of a monoid have to be trivialized by its group completion. Furthermore, almost all important examples of monoids are either one or the other. My question is, has this been formalized anywhere? Is there maybe a decomposition theorem for monoids into their grouplike and idempotent parts?

Comment: What do you do about cancellative monoids that don't embed in a group?  They have problems not caused by idempotents.

Comment: Also what do you mean by grouplike part?  Do you mean submonoids or maybe subsemigroups  on which the group completion is injective?

Comment: Malcev gave a necessary and sufficient condition for a cancellation monoid to embed in a group. Finding such conditions for semigroups has a long and rich history. The monoid with generators $a,b,c,d$ and two relations $ab=cd$ and  $aeb=ced$ is cancellative but not group-embeddable, and of course this has no non-trivial idempotent.

Comment: For inverse monoids  the idempotents are responsible for all identifications but usually very little of the monoid embeds with the exception of the inverse hull of a group embeddable cancellative monoid

Comment: A good book about idempotent monoids (and other subjects), although I don't know if it answers your question: Gondran, Michel; Minoux, Michel (2008). Graphs, Dioids and Semirings: New Models and Algorithms, Springer-Verlag.

Comment: I asked a related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/371310/11640) about rigs. The answer seems to be no.

Answer (score 2):

For *finite* semigroups (and thus monoids), the [Krohn–Rhodes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krohn%E2%80%93Rhodes_theory) gives a decomposition into (simple) groups and aperiodic semigroups (subsemigroups of the flip-flop, which is idempotent). However, the decomposition is more complicated than a separation into a “group-like part” and an “idempotent part”; it is in terms of iterated wreath products (or alternatively, iterated semidirect products, I guess).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but there may be some connection. The following situation is frequent: a monoid $M$, an equivalence relation $R$ on $M$ which is compatible with the monoid operator, and $M/R$ is an idempotent monoid. Examples:

- Polynomials with a positive highest-degree coefficient, as an additive cancellative monoid:
  $P \mathbin R Q$ is $\operatorname{deg}(P) = \operatorname{deg}(Q)$.
- Functions $\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ as an additive cancellative monoid, with [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) equivalence relation on some point $a$ (where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ or $a=+\infty$ or $a=-\infty$):
  $f \mathbin R g$ is $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(g(x))$ as $x \to a$.
- Sets with infinite cardinal, operation is union:
  $A \mathbin R B$ is $\operatorname{card}(A) = \operatorname{card}(B)$.
- Geometric or topological sets, with union:
  $\mathbin R$ is having the same dimension (for *some* dimensions, e.g. Hausdorff).

All these examples share the same pattern: the resulting idempotent monoid is a totally ordered set, and the operator is $\max$. One could build more complex examples with the same ingredients, e.g. multiple-variable polynomials, with $\operatorname{deg}$ being the set of highest-degree terms, but that looks artificial.

One possible question: given an idempotent monoid, can it always be considered as the quotient of a cancellative monoid?

Comment: Free monoid are cancellative so all monoids are quotients of cancellative monoids.  Also every monoid has a universal  quotient that is idempotent

Comment: What does "with their equivalence relation on $+\infty$" mean? Does it mean that the difference of the functions tends to $0$, that their quotient is well defined near $+\infty$ and that its limit is $1$, or something else?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for your edits. This was one of my first posts (in MO or MSE), so I was not fully aware of typographic rules. As for your question, the equivalence relation I had in mind is the "Big O" one. I shall state that in the text.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1166510), my pleasure, and I hope you've been enjoying the experience here! Just so you know, while it's always good to be semantically correct, $R$ vs. $\mathbin R$ `$R$ vs. $\mathbin R$` makes no difference in rendering; the only difference comes when a binary op. is surrounded by things on which to operate: $A R B$ vs. $A \mathbin R B$ `$A R B$ vs. $A \mathbin R B$`. Lots of things TeX already knows are binary operators, like `A + B`, but you have to tell it about $R$ specifically. You can also suppress the built-in behaviour: $A{+}B$ `A{+}B`.